# Win7 VirtualBox Server with TeamCity keeps BSODing

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, bsod, teamcity

I'm testing out TeamCity with a small project (one checkin per day or so, small code base) on a Windows 7 VM in VirtualBox. I've had many successful VMs  on this host, some of which were also Windows 7, without any problems.

I'm not sure why, but this particular guest seems to BSOD daily. Usually, it's when I'm doing something, like installing MbUnit or running a build in TeamCity.

How can I troubleshoot this and possibly fix it?

FYI, the HD is 38.8/50GB (non-fixed-size), and it has 3GB of RAM with two processors.